# Is there any city now that has portals to all the other cities?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It's been a long time since I played. When I last played, Dalaran had portals to all the original cities, but they are gone now. Is there a new city with portals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mists of Pandaria capital shrines in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms in Pandaria have portals to all major cities, plus Dalaran and Shattrath. You can ask a mage for a portal to these shrines. Please note that extremely low level players might get attacked by high level birds.

In addition, the faction base on the Ashran island has portals to 3 major cities: Orgrimmar, Thunder Bluff and Undercity for Horde, and Stormwind, Ironforge and (I think) Darnassus on Alliance side.

Comment: Yes, Darnassus, though that portal is well hidden behind the auction house...